# .htaccess : Removing unwanted symbols from the end of the URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

```
example.com/category/fruits&quot;&gt;unwanted
example.com/subcategory/apple&quot;&gt;&Fweds
```

I want to remove unwanted symbols which are after **fruits***
so that it becomes:

```
example.com/category/fruits
example.com/subcategory/apple
```

I tried but does not help me :

```
#removing unwanted symbols from the end
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(category/(.*)/[\w-]++). /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE] 


RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(subcategory/(.*)/[\w-]++). /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This single rule should work for both the cases:

```sh
RewriteRule ^((?:sub)?category/[\w-]++). /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Remember there is only one `/` after `category` or `subcategory` before matching `fruits` which is matched using possessive quantifier `[\w-]++` to disallow backtracking.

Or if `category` is just a placeholder:

```sh
RewriteRule ^((?:subcategory|category)/[\w-]++). /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: thanks for editing and making more simpler!! And yes like always, this worked again!!

Comment: please see my latest question

Comment: Thankyou! I already got the answer, Maybe I got late to ping you.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown attempts/rules, please try following. You could combine both the rules shown in your rules file. Please these rules at top of your htaccess file.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(category|subcategory)/([^/]*)/([^&]*)&.* /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```